# How to deal with constants when equating two potential energies?

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, physics, mathematical-physics

First let me ensure that the problem I am having is from a Physics book. But the problem is totally related to mathematics. Hence I think that this question here may not be illegitimate.

Using the concept of inverse square law of magnetic monopoles, [this book](https://archive.org/stream/ATreatiseOnElectricityMagnetism-Volume2/Maxwell-ATreatiseOnElectricityMagnetismVolume2#page/n0/mode/2up) derives an equation for PE between two magnetic monopoles:

$$M=-\int X dx=-PP'\int \dfrac{1}{r^2} \dfrac{x'-x}{r}dx=-PP'\int \dfrac{x'-x}{r^3} dx=\dfrac{PP'}{r}+C$$

If we define reference point of magnetic monopole at infinity, $C=0$ and PE at a point becomes: 
$M=\dfrac{PP'}{r}$

Now by adding all the dipoles of two magnets, [the book](https://archive.org/stream/ATreatiseOnElectricityMagnetism-Volume2/Maxwell-ATreatiseOnElectricityMagnetismVolume2#page/n69/mode/2up) derives an equation for PE between two magnets which is the same as PE between two closed circuits.

$$M=-\int X dx= \left( -\oint^{s'}_0 \oint^{s}_0 \dfrac{\vec{ds}.\vec{ds'}}{r}+C 
 \right) ii'$$

Since reference position of all magnetic monopoles are defined at infinity, reference position of magnet is also at infinity. Therefore $C=0$ and PE at a position becomes:

$$M=-\int X dx=-\oint^{s'}_0 \oint^{s}_0 \dfrac{\vec{ds}.\vec{ds'}}{r}ii'$$

---

In [another page](https://archive.org/stream/ATreatiseOnElectricityMagnetism-Volume2/Maxwell-ATreatiseOnElectricityMagnetismVolume2#page/n193/mode/2up), this book also derives another equation for PE between two closed circuits.

$$X=-\dfrac{\partial (-\oint^{s'}_0 \oint^{s}_0 \rho \text{ } {\vec{ds}.\vec{ds'})} }{\partial x}ii'
=-\dfrac{\partial (-\oint^{s'}_0 \oint^{s}_0 \rho \text{ } {\vec{ds}.\vec{ds'}) +a+C} }{\partial x}ii'$$

where 
'$a$' is a constant

'$C$' is an arbitrary constant depending on reference point.

Therefore:

$$M=-\int X dx=  \left[ \left(  -\oint^{s'}_0 \oint^{s}_0 \rho \text{ } {\vec{ds}.\vec{ds'}} \right) +a+C  \right]  ii'$$

---

Now **while equating the two potential energies**:

We note that if we consider the same reference point, the two arbitrary constants (in the two equations of potential energies) are equal. Therefore:

$$-\oint^{s'}_0 \oint^{s}_0 \dfrac{\vec{ds}.\vec{ds'}}{r}ii'
=\left[  \left(  -\oint^{s'}_0 \oint^{s}_0 \rho \text{ } {\vec{ds}.\vec{ds'}} \right) +a \right] ii'$$

---

[The book](https://archive.org/stream/ATreatiseOnElectricityMagnetism-Volume2/Maxwell-ATreatiseOnElectricityMagnetismVolume2#page/n195/mode/2up) gives $\rho=\frac{1}{r}$ after equating the two potential energies. This is only possible if constant $a=0$. How can we ascertain that '$a$' must be zero?

Comment: What book is this?

Answer (score 4):

You can actually begin with 
\begin{align}
M &=-\int Xdx=\dfrac{qq{^\prime}}{r}+C \hspace{4mm}\mbox{ and }
\\M& =-\int Xdx=p \text{ } qq{^\prime}+D,
\end{align}
where $C$ and $D$ are constants. 
By setting the two potentials equal to each other, we see that 
$$
\dfrac{qq{^\prime}}{r}+C = p \text{ } qq{^\prime}+D. 
$$
Since the constant terms must equate to each other, we see that $C$ must equal $D$. 
It also follows that $p=\frac{1}{r}$.

Comment: If you can tell me which book (name and page number) these equations are coming from, then I can deduce this more clearly with more detail.

Comment: Equations (31) and (36) (from Maxwell's treatise): [Link](https://archive.org/stream/ATreatiseOnElectricityMagnetism-Volume2/Maxwell-ATreatiseOnElectricityMagnetismVolume2#page/n193/mode/2up)

Comment: @Joe Thanks. I will take a look.

Comment: @Joe Your book states that $r=\sqrt{(x'-x)^2 + (y'-y)^2+(z'-z)^2}$ is a function of $\vec{x}=\langle x,y,z \rangle$ and $p$ is a function of $r$ (see Equation (24) for the electromagnetic setting). So $p$ is also a function of $\vec{x}$. After computing the two $\textit{integrals}$, it is clear that additional constants cannot drop out of the terms $\frac{qq'}{r}$ and $p\:qq'$ since you are doing improper integrals (if you were to do proper integrals, then constants produced are already grouped in $C$ or $D$, and we would know the values of $C$ and $D$).

Comment: MeeSeong: I have edited the whole question. Please take a look at the edit.