# How to deal with constants when equating two potential energies? Part II

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, vector-analysis, physics, mathematical-physics

I had asked a previous question with title "[How to deal with constants when equating two potential energies?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2666253/how-to-deal-with-constants-when-equating-two-potential-energies)". I didn't get a convincing answer and I kept on pondering it for some days. I think I have got the answer now. **Please ensure whether I am right**.

There are two closed curves $s$ and $s'$ in space from which arc lengths are measured in a defined direction.

The following symbols have their usual meanings:

\begin{equation}
\vec{ds} = \text {element of curve } s\\
\vec{ds'} = \text {element of curve } s'\\
x_0 = \text{displacement of curve $s$ as a whole without rotation along $x$-axis }\\
\epsilon = \text {angle between } \vec{ds} \text{ and } \vec{ds'}\\
r = \text {distance between points on curves } s \text{ and } s'= \text {function of independent variables $s, s', x_0, y_0, z_0$}\\
\rho = \text{function of }r\\
a = \text {an arbitrary constant}
\end{equation}

We start with the last equation of previous question:

\begin{align}
-\oint^{s'}_0 \oint^{s}_0 \dfrac{\vec{ds}.\vec{ds'}}{r}ii'
&=\left[  \left(  -\oint^{s'}_0 \oint^{s}_0 \rho \text{ } {\vec{ds}.\vec{ds'}} \right) +a \right] ii'\\
\Rightarrow  \oint^{s'}_0 \oint^{s}_0 \dfrac{\vec{ds}.\vec{ds'}}{r}
&=  \left(  \oint^{s'}_0 \oint^{s}_0 \rho \text{ } {\vec{ds}.\vec{ds'}} \right) +a\\
\Rightarrow  \oint^{s'}_0 \oint^{s}_0 \dfrac{\vec{ds}.\vec{ds'}}{r}
=& \oint^{s'}_0 \oint^{s}_0 \rho \text{ } {\vec{ds}.\vec{ds'}}+
\oint^{s'}_0 \oint^{s}_0 f(s,s') \text{ } {{ds} \text{ } {ds'} \text{ } \cos{\epsilon} }\\
\end{align}

(where $\cos{\epsilon}$ is a function of $s$ and $s'$; and $f(s,s')$ is an arbitrary function of $s$ and $s'$ so that

$a=
\oint^{s'}_0 \oint^{s}_0 f(s,s') \text{ } {{ds} \text{ } {ds'} \text{ } \cos{\epsilon} }$)

\begin{align}
\tag{1}
\Rightarrow  \oint^{s'}_0 \oint^{s}_0 \dfrac{\vec{ds}.\vec{ds'}}{r}
&=\oint^{s'}_0 \oint^{s}_0 \rho \text{ } {\vec{ds}.\vec{ds'}}+
\oint^{s'}_0 \oint^{s}_0 f(s,s') \text{ } {\vec{ds}.\vec{ds'}}\\
\Rightarrow  \oint^{s'}_0 \oint^{s}_0 \dfrac{\vec{ds}.\vec{ds'}}{r}
=&\oint^{s'}_0 \oint^{s}_0 \left[ \rho+f(s,s')  \right] \text{ } {\vec{ds}.\vec{ds'}}\\
\tag{2}
\Rightarrow \frac{1}{r}&=\rho +f(s,s')\\
\Rightarrow \dfrac{\partial }{\partial x_0}  \left(  \dfrac{1}{r}   \right) 
&=\dfrac{\partial \left[ \rho+f(s,s')  \right]}{\partial x_0}\\
\Rightarrow \dfrac{\partial }{\partial x_0}  \left(  \dfrac{1}{r}   \right) 
&=\dfrac{\partial \rho}{\partial x_0}\\
\Rightarrow \dfrac{d}{dr} \left(  \dfrac{1}{r}\right)  \dfrac{\partial r}{\partial x_0}  
&=\dfrac{d \rho}{dr}      \dfrac{\partial r}{\partial x_0}\\
\Rightarrow \dfrac{d}{dr} \left(  \dfrac{1}{r}\right)  \dfrac{\partial r}{\partial s}  
&=\dfrac{d \rho}{dr}      \dfrac{\partial r}{\partial s}\\
\tag{3}
\Rightarrow \dfrac{\partial }{\partial s}  \left(  \dfrac{1}{r}   \right) 
&=\dfrac{\partial \rho}{\partial s}\\
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\tag{2}
\Rightarrow \dfrac{1}{r}&=\rho +f(s,s')\\
\Rightarrow \dfrac{\partial }{\partial s}  \left( \dfrac{1}{r} \right)
&=\dfrac{\partial \rho }{\partial s}+\dfrac{\partial [f(s,s')] }{\partial s}\\
\Rightarrow \dfrac{\partial [f(s,s')] }{\partial s}&=0
\end{align}
(by $3$)

\begin{align}
\Rightarrow f(s,s') &= constant\\
\Rightarrow \oint^{s'}_0 \oint^{s}_0 f(s,s') \text{ } {\vec{ds}.\vec{ds'}}
&=f(s,s') \oint^{s'}_0 \oint^{s}_0 \text{ } {\vec{ds}.\vec{ds'}}\\
\Rightarrow a &= f(s,s') \times0
&=0 \\
\end{align}

because $$\oint^s_0 ds \cos {\epsilon}=0$$

[image]

Comment: There are so many things wrong here, it is hard to even figure out where to start. What is this "\oint^{s}_0"? $s,s'$ are curves, not numbers. They are not limits of integration. And further, that circle means a closed curve, so they are curves that begin and end in the same point. Next, what is "a function of $s$ and $s'$". $s, s'$ are curves, not coordinates. You can define functions on spaces of curves, but that is evidently not what you mean here - not with the integration you are using.

Comment: Also, step (2) where you drop the integrals is completely unjustified. $$\int_0^\pi \sin x\,dx = 2 = \int_0^\pi \frac 2\pi\, dx$$ but $\sin x \ne \frac 2\pi$.

Comment: BTW, when I follow the links in the other post, I don't see this mysterious arbitrary constant $a$ added to another arbitrary constant $C$ mentioned anywhere in it.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I am reading [Maxwell's treatise-Article 511](https://archive.org/stream/ATreatiseOnElectricityMagnetism-Volume2/Maxwell-ATreatiseOnElectricityMagnetismVolume2#page/n187/mode/2up). Here I think it is written that $s$ and $s'$ are arc lengths of curves measured in a defined direction.

Comment: Also, I see in step (2), we cannot drop the integrals. But why does Maxwell do it in [Article 524](https://archive.org/stream/ATreatiseOnElectricityMagnetism-Volume2/Maxwell-ATreatiseOnElectricityMagnetismVolume2#page/n195/mode/2up)

Comment: $a$ is the difference between arbitrary constants in the two expressions for $M$ in the last equation of previous question. I don't see any reason why the two arbitrary constants in the two expressions for $M$ must be equal.